# Convert timestamp string to Timestamp('yyyy-mm-dd H:M:S+0000', tz='UTC')

Tags: pandas, string, datetime, timestamp, strptime

I have a timestamp string (end_time = '2021-07-22T14:00:00Z') and I need to convert it to a timestamp in this format: Timestamp('2021-07-22 14:00:00+0000', tz='UTC').

This is my code to convert str to datetime, but the output is not what I really want to be:

```
end_time = '2021-07-22T14:00:00Z'
end_time = datetime.strptime(end_time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%Sz')
end_time

Output: datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 22, 14, 0)
```

If somebody has a clue how to deal with this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost done. All that remains is to run

```
end_time = pd.Timestamp(end_time, tz='UTC')
```

Comment: Many thanks Philip! Your answer solved my problem :)